# Add Image in Word Open SDK + dotnet core

Tags: image, .net-core, com-interop, cpu-word, openxml-sdk

I am trying to add an image to the word document using dotnet core and Open SDK library. Followed the exact same instruction as per the MSDN article. The code runs ok, but while trying to open document its says the document is corrupted.

[Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-a-word-processing-document?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[image: Error while Opening]

Used the OpenSDK Productivity tool and validated the document. Showing this error
[image]

Have confirmed that the Image Type are same. Not able to understand whats wrong.

```
    private const string RefrenceKeyWord = "rId";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InsertAPicture(document, fileName);
    }

    public static void InsertAPicture(string document, string fileName)
    {
        Int64Value imageWidth = 5731510L;
        Int64Value imageHeight = 3820795L;
        //using (var image = new Bitmap(fileName))
        //{
        //    imageWidth = image.GetWidthInEMUs() / 10;
        //    imageHeight = image.GetHeightInEMUs() / 10;
        //}

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;
            
            ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                imagePart.FeedData(stream);
            }
            //## start of new Code ##
            var maxId = mainPart.Parts
                .Where(p => p.RelationshipId.StartsWith(RefrenceKeyWord))
                .Select(p => 
                Convert.ToInt32(p.RelationshipId.Replace(RefrenceKeyWord, 
                 "")))
                .Max();

            mainPart.ChangeIdOfPart(imagePart, $"{RefrenceKeyWord}{maxId + 1}");
            //## end of new Code ##
            AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), imageWidth, imageHeight);
        }
    }

    private static void AddImageToBody(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId, Int64Value width, Int64Value height)
    {

        // Define the reference of the image.
        var element =
             new Drawing(
                 new DW.Inline(
                     new DW.Extent() { Cx = width, Cy = height },
                     new DW.EffectExtent()
                     {
                         LeftEdge = 0L,
                         TopEdge = 0L,
                         RightEdge = 2540L,
                         BottomEdge = 8255L
                     },
                     new DW.DocProperties()
                     {
                         Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                         Name = "Picture 1",
                         
                     },
                     new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                         new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                     new A.Graphic(
                         new A.GraphicData(
                             new PIC.Picture(
                                 new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                     {
                                         Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                         Name = "Picture 1"
                                     },
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties(new A.PictureLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true, NoChangeArrowheads = true })),
                                 new PIC.BlipFill(
                                     new A.Blip(
                                         new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                             new A.BlipExtension()
                                             {
                                                 Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}",
                                             })
                                     )
                                     {
                                         Embed = relationshipId,
                                         //CompressionState =
                                         //A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                     },
                                     new A.Stretch(
                                         new A.FillRectangle())),
                                 new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                     new A.Transform2D(
                                         new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                         new A.Extents() { Cx = width, Cy = height }),
                                     new A.PresetGeometry(
                                         new A.AdjustValueList()
                                     )
                                     { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                         )
                         { Uri = "https://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                 )
                 {
                     DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     EditId = "50D07946"
                 });

        SectionProperties sectPr = (SectionProperties)wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements.Last();

        // var p = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement;
        // var p1 = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.FirstChild;

        var p1 =  new Paragaph(new Run(element));
        // Append the reference to body, the element should be in a Run.
        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertBefore(p1, sectPr);
    }
```

Comment: I think I was able to narrow down what is causing the problem. The reference Id which gets generated by this code  mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart) is a big number "R49ac375f85104695". When I manually changed the pattern to word pattern "rId10" in the document.xml.rels and corresponding change in the document.xml, the document opened correctly. Now not sure how to fix this programmatically.

Comment: I have updated the code to change the reference id based on a simple logic. Not sure if this the right approach but for now it works for me. If anyone knows the root cause or a better way to do, please comment.  I almost lost a full night sleep just to get this working, hoping this would help others too.